# mysql select entries between a date

Tags: mysql, select

have a sql table with start- and end-date:

```
room | start | end
5 | 2023-01-07 | 2023-01-14
6 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-05
```

now I try to select all entries where a date is between "start date" and "end date":

```
SELECT * FROM pr_calendar WHERE start <= '2023-01-13' AND end <= '2023-01-13'
```

it shows me the entry with id 6. how can I make this selection? thanks

Comment: You probably meant to type: `end >= '2023-01-13'`.    Or use: `start <= '2023-01-13' AND '2023-01-13' <= end`

Answer (score 2):

> now I try to select all entries where a date is between "start date"
> and "end date":

Try,

```
SELECT pc.* 
FROM pr_calendar pc 
WHERE '2023-01-13' between start  AND end ;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/JxhqZtOA)

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot - and learned the between function;-)